Clarification about how 'Relative XPath' actually work?
I've read a lot of documents related to Absolute Xpath and Relative XPath, but I still have no idea how Relative XPath works, for Absolute Path, an element can be found from the root based on the desired path, how about Relative XPath?
I would appreciate any ideas or suggestions you may have for me.
